# When will session_id() be null?

Tags: php, session, null

We're currently facing an issue that `session_id()` returns `null` or an *empty* response, which we can see in our logs. We, of course, started the session and it also works for 95% of the time.

My question now is - when will the PHP `session_id()` return `null`, `""` or simply is *empty*.

Does somebody also facing a similar problem with this function and already can tell me a workaround which doesn't looks like:
`session_start()` till there is a session.

Comment: Could be a plethora of things, but most likely the session isn't starting properly... which could be: output before `session_start()`, unable to write to session path (permissions issue, space issue, etc), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The way I know:**

`session_id()` can be `null` if `session_start()` returned `false`. Could be possible if you've got any output before using `session_start()`.

This output for sure can be conditional, so `session_id()` wouldnt result in `null` every time.

**Edit:**

- Oh and just read: If the access to the session path is restricted if would also behave this way.
- What about `if(session_id() = null)`-Typo which would maybe set your `session_id` to `null`?

Comment: You're right - we're currently not checking if `session_start()` returns false or not - anyway the session path access rights are correct - what would be the right way to handle if it returns `false`?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do in this case. You could for sure go with `if(!session_start()) {  }`. The question is > what then? <.

Comment: Right - sorry for the unclear question. Is there any kind of best practice - how to handle that.

Comment: There is no "how to handle that" as long as you dont know why your session returns null. Find the problem and solve it. You'll probably have no reason to catch the null then.